# Excel Macro Merge Cells Based on Other Merge

Tags: vba, excel

I need to do merge and center for over 7,000+ rows. There are 3 columns of the numerous columns that will have data that can be merged. I cannot delete rows. I took a small snippet below to hopefully demonstrate this.

I utilized this macro that I found to merge row A. It works great. The issue is that Column B and C were merging differently. I need the merging to be based on how Column A merged. Column A is unique, it never repeats. Column B and C may repeat so merging must be based on column A.

Code that was used to merge column A:

```
Sub MergeSameCell()
    'Updateby20131127
    Dim Rng As Range, xCell As Range
    Dim xRows As Integer
    xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    xRows = WorkRng.Rows.Count
    For Each Rng In WorkRng.Columns
        For i = 1 To xRows - 1
            For j = i + 1 To xRows
                If Rng.Cells(i, 1).Value <> Rng.Cells(j, 1).Value Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            WorkRng.Parent.Range(Rng.Cells(i, 1), Rng.Cells(j - 1, 1)).Merge
            i = j - 1
        Next
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This allowed me to merge unique codes in column A (over 7000 rows). The next thing I need is to merge the two columns to the right of it based on the merging of the column A.

Example: I need column B & C to be merged based on Column A. I can't do the merge macro listed above that I did for column A because the '50' in column B merges across Column A (01, 02, 03). Instead, I need each to be merged in order regardless of what the next group's value is.

What I have:
[image: Table Before]

What I need:
[image: Table After]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: SO really works when you show the code you've attempted *to solve the* **specific** *problem you are asking about*. Right now, you are asking us to code your new requirements for you, which is outside the scope of SO.

Answer (score 0):

I determined the answer. I will post it here in case someone else faces this issue. I tweaked the original code and saved it in the Macro. Before doing any sorting, Select all rows of column A, then hit F5 to run....

```
Sub MergeSameCell()
'Updateby20131127
Dim Rng As Range, xCell As Range
Dim xRows As Integer
xTitleId = "Multiple Merge & Center"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, 
Type:=8)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
xRows = WorkRng.Rows.Count
For Each Rng In WorkRng.Columns
    For i = 1 To xRows - 1
        For j = i + 1 To xRows
            If Rng.Cells(i, 1).Value <> Rng.Cells(j, 1).Value Then
                Exit For
            ElseIf Rng.Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        WorkRng.Parent.Range(Rng.Cells(i, 1), Rng.Cells(j - 1, 1)).Merge
        WorkRng.Parent.Range(Rng.Cells(i, 2), Rng.Cells(j - 1, 2)).Merge
        WorkRng.Parent.Range(Rng.Cells(i, 3), Rng.Cells(j - 1, 3)).Merge
        i = j - 1
    Next
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```