# Merge content in column based on ID

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to locate a VBA script that will merge a column value (not concatenate the rows). This will be a recurring report and it is thousands of rows. I found one that will merge row A fine but I need it to also merge the values within their own cells that are tied to the Group in column A. It can't merge for any column not selected since other column data is unique (see column E for example)

[image: Here is an example of the raw data (not the actual data since it is sensitive information):]

[image: Here is what I am trying to achieve:]

I have this as a starting point for column A but it gives a runtime error and I cannot just run this on column B since it would not do it based on column A.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MergeSameCells()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim rng As Range

MergeCells:

For Each rng In Selection

If rng.Value = rng.Offset(1, 0).Value And rng.Value <> "" Then

Range(rng, rng.Offset(1, 0)).Merge

GoTo MergeCells

End If

Next

End Sub
```

Apologies in advance for the formatting of this. I haven't posted much but I use this site frequently.

Comment: This post was recommended when I posted my question. I highlighted column A and it worked for columns A, B & C. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48644787/excel-macro-merge-cells-based-on-other-merge
How would I edit this to also do column D?

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it. Added another range to the merge.

```
Sub MergeSameCell()
Dim Rng As Range, xCell As Range
Dim xRows As Integer
xTitleId = "Multiple Merge & Center"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
xRows = WorkRng.Rows.Count
For Each Rng In WorkRng.Columns
For i = 1 To xRows - 1
For j = i + 1 To xRows
If Rng.Cells(i, 1).Value <> Rng.Cells(j, 1).Value Then
Exit For
ElseIf Rng.Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then
Exit For
End If
Next
WorkRng.Parent.Range(Rng.Cells(i, 1), Rng.Cells(j - 1, 1)).Merge
WorkRng.Parent.Range(Rng.Cells(i, 2), Rng.Cells(j - 1, 2)).Merge
WorkRng.Parent.Range(Rng.Cells(i, 3), Rng.Cells(j - 1, 3)).Merge
WorkRng.Parent.Range(Rng.Cells(i, 4), Rng.Cells(j - 1, 4)).Merge
i = j - 1
Next
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```